# texhash cannot open ls-R texlive 2022

Tags: texlive

I have recently switched from MiKTeX to Texlive 2022 (by uninstalling MiKTeX then installing Texlive) on the Windows 11 x64 platform. I tried to run the `texhash` command but it turned out with errors. I am sure that the Texlive binary directory (in my case `C:\texlive\2022\bin\win32`) is in PATH. Is it because it's `win32`, not `win64`?

Here are the errors I've got:

```
C:\Users\[myusername]>texhash
Cannot open C:/texlive/texmf-local/ls-R to write.
Cannot open C:/texlive/2022/texmf-config/ls-R to write.
Cannot open C:/texlive/2022/texmf-var/ls-R to write.
Cannot open C:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/ls-R to write.
texhash: Done.
```

Comment: Maybe you should use cmd under the administrator's identity.

Comment: Oh, I see, the problem is solved. Thanks. @Stephen